# Regarding : Insert value in list

Tags: python

So I would like to take a list like:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

and then add an item right before the one in position "i". For example, if i = 2 the list would become:

```
[1, 2, "desired number", 3, 4]
```

How could I do that in python? Thanks ahead

Comment: you could try : `list_name.insert(index, value)`

Comment: Google "python list insert"

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
L = [1, 2, 3, 4]
L.insert(2, 0)
# [1, 2,0, 3, 4]
```